# Is there a package for doing this in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, packages, code

I'd like to do something like this

[image]

What would be the code? does it use a package for doing the `$$f\mapsto f\circ \pi$$` part?

Comment: Not at all. Math mode will do. Either between `$` signs (as you already have it) or in display mode between `\[` `\]` or `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`. Or are you referring to the indentation?

Comment: I think you might be interested in [_Math Mode_](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode) by Herbert Voß which provides much useful information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \pi^{\ast} \colon C^{k}(P,N) &\to     C^{k}(M,N)  \\[-1ex]
  f                            &\mapsto f \circ \pi
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Remember to use `\colon` for maps; with `:` you will get wrong spacing acound the colon.

Comment: »I don't think there is a package for this« - but you _are_ loading `amsmath` ;)

Comment: @cgnieder Well, I meant a package for typing only this specifically in an easier way. :)

Comment: the problem with this approach is the spacing between the upper and the lower part I guess it's too big, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Dion See updated answer.

Comment: @Dion You can change `-1ex` to whatever length fits your needs.

Comment: I'll try... =D..

Answer (score 5):

You can use a self-defined command with a better syntax than using five arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array}

\NewDocumentCommand{\map}{s m >{\SplitArgument{1}{\to}}m >{\SplitArgument{1}{\mapsto}}m}
 {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\onelinemap{#2}#3#4}{\twolinemap{#2}#3#4}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\onelinemap}{mmmmm}
 {#1\colon #2\to#3,\quad #4\mapsto #5}

\NewDocumentCommand{\twolinemap}{mmmmm}
 {\begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{{}}l@{}}
  #1\colon #2 & \to #3\\
  #4 & \mapsto #5
  \end{array}}

\begin{document}
\[
\map*{\pi}{C^k(P,N) \to C^k(M,N)}{f \mapsto \pi\circ f}
\]
\[
\map{\pi}{C^k(P,N) \to C^k(M,N)}{f \mapsto \pi\circ f}
\]
\end{document}
```

The `*`-variant prints a one line version.

[image]

Comment: you could also define this way:

\newcommand{\map}[5]{\displaystyle #1:#2&\longrightarrow #3\\[-2ex]#4&\longmapsto #5}

The command would be:
\begin{align*}
\map{\pi}{C^k(P, N)}{C^k(M, N)}{f}{\pi\circ f}
\end{align*}

\end{document}

The way I defined it makes it works only inside the align environment...
I guess you save some charachters when typing..